# Name of equation

Tags: real-analysis

For natural $n \ge 2$, I'm given following equation:
$$\frac{x+x^{-1}}{x^n + x^{-n}} = \frac 1n$$

Is it some known thing with a name so that I could find something about it?

If not, I need help with proof that when we rewrite it as polynomial $p_n(x) = 0$ it has two *positive* roots, $\alpha_n \in (0, 1)$ and $\beta_n \in (1, 3)$. I can proof that both exists using Intermediate value theorem, but how to proof there is nothing more?

Comment: Are you sure it is part of the task that ther is "nothing more" (i.e. no more positive roots? Or no more real roots?)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Being literal, in task is written (in poor translation) "man is able to show that there exists exactly two positive roots", but from what I know about nature of lab I'm expected to show it. In fact, with another parts of excercise I need to write 10 pages in Latex about that equation.

Comment: I don't know about this specific equation, but it belongs to a class of equations called *reciprocal equations*. Many of the older freely available books on the topic "Theory of Equations" will have a lot of information about such equations.

Comment: With some manipulation one can show that the stationary points of the equation $y = nx + nx^{-1} - x^n - x^{-n}$ satisfy $x(x^n - 1)(x^{n + 1} + 1) = 0$. Perhaps it is possible to establish some relationship between the number of turning points and the maximum number of roots.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, from future, the proof is quite easy. You only use Descartes' rule of signs and it is done.